# Regarding the virtual memory management of Windows 11

Tags: windows, memory, paging, virtual-memory, windows-11

I want to know if it uses paging, segmentation, or paging with segmentation? I guess it's the same from w10, but if that's the case, I still want to know. Actually, I know it uses paging, but does it use segmentation too or paging with segmentation? (and if it uses, so how it does?)

I read some documents, searched here and some other foruns, but I still doesn't know for sure